# PHP Application Structure/Pattern - 2 sites with shared libraries and assets

Tags: php, structure

I'm having a bit of an application structure design dilemma.

I have created a web app that creates online surveys. It all works fine, but I would now like to create a new site that does different types of online surveys. This new site will be pretty much 95% similar in terms of layout, logic, functions, etc.

Rather than duplicate all the code from the current web app, I'd like the new app to share in the "fountain of knowledge" created by the current app - so to speak.

Can anyone enlighten me with their experiences of doing this sort of thing? Their best practices?

As a rough guide, I'm currently thinking of using symlinks for all the major logic files (library.php, functions.php, etc), and then deciding which logic to use based on which URL the user logged-in from.

Does that sound like a good or bad idea?

Would it be any better or worse to divide the whole system in to 3 sites, with the site in the middle containing all the common elements and logic? This middle site would have no independent use - it would be used from either of the 2 applications looking for functionality and assets, etc.

Any help and experience on this matter is very much appreciated indeed.

I'm very wary of going down a dead-end solution.

Kind Regards,
Seb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good solution if:

- you host your website yourself and creating symlinks between differents virtual hosts is not a problem
- you won't have to make significative changes between the 2 websites

But instead of using symlinks, I could take advantage of PHP's `include_path` directive and put the common libraries in this path. This way, just write your includes relative to this path, the files will be accessible from any site you want on the same server.

The second advantage of using include_path is you can bypass any open_basedir directives which wouldn't allow you to include files which are not in the same virtual host base dir.

Comment: i agree, include_path is definitely the way to go about this! and all you would have to do to make this work is update some include/require statements.

Comment: Excellent - will definitely have a look in to this. I guess though I could just point an include() at the folder where I keep all my core libraries? Or does include_path have any advantage over doing this? Cheers.

Comment: The advantage of using `include_path` is you don't have to worry where the files actually are. Just `include 'file.php'` If `file.php` is found in the current dir, then it includes this one. If not, it looks inside the `include_path`. You also don't have to update every single include if the library path changes, you simply update the include_path. Another advantage is you could decide to copy a library to the current dir to "overwrite" the common one. Adds some freedom in case you want to change something in one website only.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks very much all. Going to chose this route and start breaking out all the common stuff and shove it in to a core folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it...

- Create a core library.
- Create you 2 site directories.
- Create site specific code folders in
  each site.
- Create core library folders in each
  site that simlink to the main core
  library created.

Comment: That definitely makes sense, but seems like an awful lot of work due to one of these sites already being established and operational. I would definitely have chosen this route if I had known this was going to be the case where I would need another site (and possibly more). The joys of web development ;-)

Comment: its the trade of between doing that wprk and then duplicating everything you do during support phase of your 2(maybe more) sites. IMO the time investment is MORE than worth it.